# how can i get all review from google+ using api

Tags: api, google-api, web-scraping, google-plus

i am beginner to google+ developer API and i want to grab user review from any about page for example https://plus.google.com/116018016837619707952/about

i have tried using curl call but didn't get success for all reviews.
also seen the content of document :https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get
 can You just give me the idea about google api to grab review data.

Answer (score 0):

Reviews are [not considered part](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=260) of the Google+ Platform. You have to use the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details).